# unable to typecast from float* to char*

Tags: c++, function, pointers

error while pointer typecasting

without typecasting the float* to char*, the code runs fine, but when I tyepcast it, it gives the error "cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘char*’ in initialization", even though the float* and char* will be of same size, i just wanted to try it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int processing_block(char*,short*,short*,short*,char*,bool*,bool*);

#define monitor_w 640
#define monitor_h 480

int main()
{

short w=monitor_w/1.05, h=monitor_h/1.05;
short x=monitor_w/2,        y=monitor_h/2;
float zoomer=0.5f;
bool resume = false;
bool fix1 = false;


float *pfz= &zoomer;
short *psx= &x;

pfz=(char*)pfz;
char *pcz= pfz;

psx=(char*)psx;
char *pcx= psx;
processing_block(psx,&y,&w,&h,pcz,&resume,&fix1);
cout<<"\nx-\t"<<x<<"\ny-\t"<<y<<"\nw-\t"<<w<<"\nh-\t"<<h<<"\nzoomer-\t"<<zoomer<<"\nresume-\t"<<resume<<"\nfix1-\t"<<fix1<<endl;
return 0;
}

int processing_block(short* px,short* ya,short* wa,short* ha,char* pzoom,bool* resume,bool* fix1)
{
*pzoom=0.02+(*pzoom);
if((*px)-(*ya)>25)
    *resume = true;
else{
    *fix1= true;
    *pzoom=10.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your compiler is being priggish if it doesn't allow a cast to char*. A cast to `const unsigned char*` is required to work by the standard. Try that. Is your monitor really that little?

Comment: A char* is not a float*, it would allow to cast to a void* though.

Comment: "even though the float* and char* will be of same size" how does this matter? What does matter is that `float` and `char` are not of same size

Comment: `*pzoom` that's UB if you originally have a float that you can to a char. And use references instead, you are in C++, not C.

Comment: You're casting is wrong. `psx = (char*)psx;`, you cast `psx` to `char*` and then assign it back to `psx` which is of type `short*`, first error. Then you do `char *pcx = psx` so you try to put a `short*` in `char*` without cast, second error. You simply need `char *pcx = (char*)psx`, without the `psx = (char*)psx`, but this looks pretty fishy for C++ code.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `*pzoom` has well defined behaviour. `char` is allowed to alias `float` (as well as any other object). The way OP uses `pzoom` makes little sense though. It is unclear what they're trying to do.

Comment: The compiler is complaining about implicit conversions, not casts. `pfz=(char*)pfz;` does not change the type of `pfz`.

Answer (score 5):

Your compiler is correct. `char*` is not *implicitly* convertible to `float*` and vice versa.

All data pointers can however be explicitly converted (reinterpreted) to all other data pointer types, so following would be well-formed:

```
char *pcz = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pfz);
```

Note that although reinterpretation is well formed, another matter is whether indirection through the reinterpreted pointer has well defined behaviour. If the original type and the new type are not pointer-interconvertible, then the behaviour would be undefined.

`char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` are exceptional in that indirection through a pointer to them is well defined even if the pointer was reinterpreted from *any* other type as long as the pointed object exists - although, remember that behaviour is undefined if you read an indeterminate value.

Comment: But still lots of other things wrong with OP question, as this code will lead to UB.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher yes. OP's code may contain other bugs as well. I constrained my answer to what was asked.

Comment: I think in this case some additional guidance on what OP code is actually doing would be better.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher feel free to answer OP with additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
pfz=(char*)pfz; // Does nothing, maybe give an error (assigning char* to float*)
char *pcz= pfz; // Tries to assign pfz (float*) to pcz (char*)

psx=(char*)psx; // Same
char *pcx= psx; // Same
```

You should do:

```
char *pcz= (char*) pfz;
char *pcx= (char*) psx;
```